# Passing Parameters with Button Costructor

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, android-button

this here is driving me nuts...

I want to pass some Parameters with a Button Constructor

I did create myButton extending Button:

```
package com.canbluetoothinterface.utilities;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class myActivityStartButton extends Button implements OnClickListener {

protected EditText[] Array;
private String Name;
private String BufferName;
private Activity activityinstance;
public String[] sValues;
Class<?> cls;
private Method m;


public myActivityStartButton(String Name, Class<?>clsin, Context context) {
    super(context);
    cls = clsin;
    activityinstance = (Activity) context;
    setId(mygetId());
    this.Name = Name;
    init();

}

private void init(){
    setOnClickListener(this);
}

public myActivityStartButton(String Name, Class<?>clsin, Context context, Method min) {
    super(context);
    this.cls = clsin;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.m = min;
    activityinstance = (Activity) context;
    setId(mygetId());
    setTag(findViewById(mygetId()));

    init();

}

@Override
public void setId(int id) {

    super.setId(id);
}

private int mygetId() {
    int id = 0;
    BufferName = Name; 
    id = activityinstance.getResources().getIdentifier(BufferName, "id", activityinstance.getPackageName());
    return id;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        m.invoke(null, (Object)null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(activityinstance, cls );
    activityinstance.startActivity(intent);

}


}
```

In my Activity I call:

```
Start = new myActivityStartButton("act_testdriveconfiguration_btn_start", DeviceListActivity.class, this, mstartbutton);
```

But my OnClick is never called...
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: do you have added the onClickListener?

Comment: I thought setOnClickListener(this); in init(), is enough...
If not can you please offer codesnippet?

Comment: you have to add OnClickListener in your Activity

Comment: you need to set the onClickListener in your activity - `Start.setOnClickListener(Start)` this might work, but I haven´t used an onClickListener handler within the button itself, so it might be wrong. If the handler doesnt need to be in the button-class, try [this](http://android-helper.blogspot.co.at/2011/04/android-simple-button-click-example.html)

Comment: Hi, hm it doesn't work. I actually wanted to have the handler in the class. So that I dont't have to write it each time...

Comment: I think that my button doesn't even "know" that it's him that is pressed. Is 

setId(mygetId());
    setTag(findViewById(mygetId()));

Really enough to allocate the xml Button to this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.double check your init() is called.

The following code works for me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_container);

    SomeButton btn = new SomeButton(this);

    layout.addView(btn);
}


private class SomeButton extends Button implements OnClickListener {

    public SomeButton(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.w("log", "click");
    }

}
```

**NOTE:**

if your button is created in xml, you need these constructors.

```
   public setParams(String Name, Class<?>clsin,etc params)
   {
     //saving params
   }

   public SomeButton(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public SomeButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init();
    }

    public SomeButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init();
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the snippet, to clarify:
My Button already exists. I have placed it with the Graphical Layout Editor. I think the Problem is to connect this already definded Button to my myActivityStartButton. Normaly I do that with     Button somebutton =(Button)findviewByid(R.id.somebutton). But I can't use that because I need the constructor to pass the parameters

Comment: if you you place your button in xml file, why do you write this code?Start = new myActivityStartButton("act_testdriveconfiguration_btn_start", DeviceListActivity.class, this, mstartbutton); this will get a new instance

Comment: I know that I creates a new instance, but how else can I predefine actions for the onClick of a button? What I want to do is adding a button to the layout with xml. And then declare that if the button is clicked a new activity is started. I know I can do that in the Activity itself but I don't want to write it each time...
I just want to connect the object to the xml...

Comment: oh, i see, i update my answer.you can just findbyid, get the instance, and call setParams to pass your classname and other param

Comment: Ok good enough, depsite me being very lazy. I wanted to reduce lines of code to a minimum but I think 2 lines will be ok.